# Pyspark find the nearest text

Tags: python, database, pyspark, recommendation-engine, text-comparison

I'm a new user for pyspark. I want to compare text from two different dataframes (containing news information) for recommendation.

I was able to do this very easily with Python:

```py
def get_recommendations(title, cosine_sim, indices):
    idx = indices[title]
    # Get the pairwsie similarity scores
    sim_scores = list(enumerate(cosine_sim[idx]))
    print(sim_scores)
    # Sort the movies based on the similarity scores
    sim_scores = sorted(sim_scores, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
    # Get the scores for 10 most similar movies
    sim_scores = sim_scores[1:11]
    talk_indices = [i[0] for i in sim_scores]
    # Return the top 10 most
    return ted['News Data'].iloc[talk_indices]

indices = pd.Series(det.index, index=det['Unnamed: 0']).drop_duplicates()

transcripts = det['News Data']
transcripts2 = ted['News Data']

tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english')
tfidf_matrix = tfidf.fit_transform(transcripts)
tfidf_matrixx = tfidf.transform(transcripts2)
cosine_sim = linear_kernel(tfidf_matrix, tfidf_matrixx)

print(get_recommendations(0, cosine_sim, indices))
```

When I switched to pyspark, I got very different results when calculating TF-IDF. I know that computation of Cosine Similarity is required to make "news" recommendations.

I'm using following in Pyspark for tfidf calculation:

```py
df1 = sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').options(header='true', inferschema='true').load('bbcclear.csv')
df2 = sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').options(header='true', inferschema='true').load('yenisafakcategorypredict.csv')

# tokenize
tokenizer = Tokenizer().setInputCol("News Data").setOutputCol("word")
wordsData = tokenizer.transform(df2)
wordsData2 = tokenizer.transform(df1)

# vectorize
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(inputCol='word', outputCol='vectorizer').fit(wordsData)
wordsData = vectorizer.transform(wordsData)
wordsData2 = vectorizer.transform(wordsData2)

# calculate scores
idf = IDF(inputCol="vectorizer", outputCol="tfidf_features")
idf_model = idf.fit(wordsData)
wordsData = idf_model.transform(wordsData)

idf_model = idf.fit(wordsData2)
wordsData2 = idf_model.transform(wordsData2)
```

How do I compute Cosine Similarity using ID-IDF obtained above to make recommendation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is an example of TF-IDF usage in Spark from my PoC assignment. I will highly recommend to use advanced NLP frameworks like BERT than TF-IDF for meaningful similarity.

Sample dataset:

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        ["cricket sport team player"],
        ["global politics"],
        ["football sport player team"],
    ],
    ["news"]
)

+--------------------------+
|news                      |
+--------------------------+
|cricket sport team player |
|global politics           |
|football sport player team|
+--------------------------+
```

TF-IDF vectorisation and cosine similarity computation:

```py
from pyspark.ml.feature import RegexTokenizer, CountVectorizer, IDF
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline

regex_tokenizer = RegexTokenizer(gaps=False, pattern="\w+", inputCol="news", outputCol="tokens")
count_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(inputCol="tokens", outputCol="tf")
idf = IDF(inputCol="tf", outputCol="idf")
tf_idf_pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[regex_tokenizer, count_vectorizer, idf])
df = tf_idf_pipeline.fit(df).transform(df).drop("news", "tokens", "tf")
df = df.crossJoin(df.withColumnRenamed("idf", "idf2"))

@F.udf(returnType=FloatType())
def cos_sim(u, v):
  return float(u.dot(v) / (u.norm(2) * v.norm(2)))
# 

df.withColumn("cos_sim", cos_sim(F.col("idf"), F.col("idf2")))

+--------------------+--------------------+----------+
|                 idf|                idf2|   cos_sim|
+--------------------+--------------------+----------+
|(7,[0,1,2,4],[0.2...|(7,[0,1,2,4],[0.2...|       1.0|
|(7,[0,1,2,4],[0.2...|(7,[5,6],[0.69314...|       0.0|
|(7,[0,1,2,4],[0.2...|(7,[0,1,2,3],[0.2...|0.34070355|
|(7,[5,6],[0.69314...|(7,[0,1,2,4],[0.2...|       0.0|
|(7,[5,6],[0.69314...|(7,[5,6],[0.69314...|       1.0|
|(7,[5,6],[0.69314...|(7,[0,1,2,3],[0.2...|       0.0|
|(7,[0,1,2,3],[0.2...|(7,[0,1,2,4],[0.2...|0.34070355|
|(7,[0,1,2,3],[0.2...|(7,[5,6],[0.69314...|       0.0|
|(7,[0,1,2,3],[0.2...|(7,[0,1,2,3],[0.2...|       1.0|
+--------------------+--------------------+----------+
```

Comment: Thanks for help so much! This is what i was looking for. But when I run the code I get an "import numpy" error. Do you know anything about this error?

Comment: @AlpBuğraAker we can't see your `"import numpy" error` - so we have no idea what is your problem. If you have new problem then create new question on new page and you will have more place to show FULL error message and describe problem.